# What's the simplest way to fetch the value of the Authorization header of a request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, asp.net-core

#### Question

Given an `HttpRequest` with an [`Authorization` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization), what's the simplest way to fetch the *authentication type* and the *authentication credentials* of said header?

As an example, given `Authorization: Bearer YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l`, how can I get both `Bearer` and `YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l` from an `HttpRequest`?

<sub>Yes, I'm aware that the Identity framework exists. I'm not using it here. If you really want to try and change my mind we can discuss it [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c).</sub>

#### What I tried

I'm writing a function along the lines of:

```
var authorizationHeader = request.Headers["Authorization"].ToArray()[0];
var authorizationParts = authorizationHeader.Split(' ');
if (authorizationParts.Length == 2 && authorizationParts[0] == "Bearer")
{
    var tokenValue = authorizationParts[1];
    // ...
}
// ...
```

but it's very error prone and verbose. For example in the first line I haven't checked if the array contains at least one element.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's some simple middleware that will do it:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization") &&
        context.Request.Headers["Authorization"][0].StartsWith("Bearer "))
    {
        var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"][0]
            .Substring("Bearer ".Length);
        //do stuff...
    }

    await next.Invoke();
});
```

Personally though I would be less concerned with verbosity, move the above to an extension and make it more verbose, e.g. by being more explicit about what you're doing:

```
if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
    throw new SomeException(); //or whatever

var authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"][0];
if (authHeader.StartsWith("Bearer "))
{
    var token = authHeader.Substring("Bearer ".Length);
    //do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this snippet, it's not as error prone as your code but still verbose.

```
if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.StartsWith("Bearer")) {
    string credentials = authHeader.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
} else {
    //Handle what happens if that isn't the case
    throw new Exception("The authorization header is either empty or isn't Bearer.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
  const authorization = request.get('authorization')
      if (authorization && authorization.toLowerCase().startsWith('bearer ')) {
        return authorization.substring(7)
      }
      return null
```

this should work